# Firefox extension: cant use variables or functions from element movie_player on ytmusic

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

i want to code a firefox extension where i can invite people to a "Yt-Music party" and it will sync up to the host YtMusic.

The element "movie_player" contains a lot of functions and variable which could be usefull, like the current time of the song.

For some reason the getCurrentTime() function works in the webconsole, but not when i have it like this, in my extension.

Do i need extra permission to do this?

Thanks in advance

```
const ytPlayer = document.getElementById('movie_player')

const test = ytPlayer.getCurrentTime()

console.log(test)
```

[image: web console get element movie player]

[image: web console get current time]

Comment: Use ytPlayer.wrappedJSObject.getCurrentTime() in your content script.

Answer (score 0):

Extensions don't have direct access to elements on the page. You'd have to inject a [content script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts), and then pass data (via [messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Content_scripts#communicating_with_background_scripts)) between the page and the extension's [background script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Background_scripts) (or service worker) to have this type of communication. Note also that content scripts [don't get access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Sharing_objects_with_page_scripts) to things like *ytPlayer* by default either.

Comment: It's not about communication but about [accessing the main world of the page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Sharing_objects_with_page_scripts) because content scripts are isolated. For all we know from the incomplete description in the question the OP may already do it in a content script because it's also "in" extension.

Comment: @wOxxOm Not sure what you mean by *isolated* here; content scripts are injected into the page (though they have a "clean view" of the environment). If you want to get the value from `getCurrentTime()`, you'd have to do that with a content script and pass it back (via messaging) to the background script. This is what I stated in my answer, so I'm not sure with which part you're disagreeing 

Comment: Your answer is non-working without the thing I mentioned. The most important difference about a content script is that it runs in the so-called "isolated world", it's a technical term in the extensions platform, which means a content script can't call getCurrentTime because it's not a built-in DOM method but a JS function added by the page. Firefox provides an unsafe `wrappedJSObject` trick to allow direct interaction, the article is linked in my comment above.

Comment: @wOxxOm Nothing in my answer (or comment) says otherwise. The original question sounded as though the issue was with code ran from the context of a background script, rather than a content script (`wrappedJSObject` aside). That said, an explicit reference to `wrappedJSObject` is indeed a good addition.

Comment: wrappedJSObject is a crucial piece of information omitting which makes the answer incomplete to a degree that it is essentially unusable as well as possibly completely unrelated in case the OP already uses a content script.